# Как обработать программно sql запрос, если он ничего не нашел?

Tags: c++builder, sql

```
sqlzap="select * from STRIPE WHERE STRIPE = '"+RugidK+"' and (WORKID2 BETWEEN '"+c+"' AND '"+po+"')";
DataSource1->DataSet = Query1;
Query1->SQL->Clear();
Query1->SQL->Add(sqlzap);
Query1->Active = true;
```

Использую примерно такие запросы. Надо обработать, если sql ничего не нашел. Должно быть что-то вроде `if(Query1->XXXX!=0){}`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Query1->IsEmpty()) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

не совсем думаю честно, но если заюзать

```
Query1->RecordCount // возвращает количество строк<BR> 
if(Query1->RecordCount==0){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM emptytable);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if(!empty($result)) {
    //если результат не пустой
}
```